# A/C water condensation drain pipe

Tags: hvac

The condenser air-conditioning drain pipe attached to the furnace is draining water to the outside of the home. Is this normal operation?

Comment: It is not normal if it is NOT draining.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it normal that it's draining water?

Yes, that's why the condenser *has* a drain line.

> Is it normal that it's draining outside the house?

Nothing wrong with that, though they are often plumbed to drain inside if there's a convenient place (mine runs into the sump pit in the basement). The only possible issue is if it's draining in a bad location that might create a puddle and, eventually, start finding its way back into the house. However, there shouldn't be so much condenser water coming out that this should really be a worry.

Comment: Yes it's normal if it's the primary condenser drain line.  However, often there is (especially if your AC unit is in the attic) an overflow catch pan under your AC unit that's drained to an obvious spot outside the house, that will only drain water if the primary drain is clogged or there is some other problem with your AC unit.  You'll want to make sure the drain you're seeing is the primary drain, and not the overflow emergency drain.